# When using Python's subprocess for running a compiled matlab programm, environment variables are not passed

Tags: python, matlab, subprocess, environment

I am using a Linux Docker container, and the code is managed by Python. I use Python code to generate a `subprocess run` call that runs a compiled matlab program. This compiled matlab program is calling another external program that requires to read an environmental variable.

```
my_env = os.environ.copy()
cmd = f'<abs path to my compiled program>/<compiled program "{path to a file it needs to be read}"'
log.info(f"Calling the matlab function with: \n {cmd}")
res = sp.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True, env=my_env)
```

This is not working (I am using Python 3.9.15).

If I run the matlab program in the command line without Python's subprocess, the env variables are passed and the Matlab program works ok.

If I run the same command from Python, the env variables are not passed.

In Python, all the correct env variables are there (`os.getenv()` returns the proper variables, and `my_env` has the proper variables.

I am using a workaround that it is working so far:

```
cmd = (
       f'<abs path to my compiled program>/<compiled program '
       f'"{path to a file it needs to be read}" >> log_file.txt'
)
res = os.system(cmd)
if res != 0:
    die('show error message')
if os.path.isfile('log_file.txt'):
    print(open('log_file.txt','r').read())
```

But I don't think it is ideal. I would rather keep using the stdout and stderr and the subprocess call.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "This is not working" -- this isn't much detail to go on.  Can you explain the **exact** problem?  How do you know that some variables aren't being passed?  What behavior, exactly, did you see?

Comment: The internal program needs to use a tmp/ folder for calculations that it is passed as a environemnt variable. When using `subprocess run`, the calculation goes to `/tmp`, the default directory, instead of the the variable that should be read from environment variables. When running from command line or with `os.system`, it worked. When running from `subprocess run`, it is not working (so, not working = not reading the environment variables when using `subprocess run`)